# How to get multiple string values in return in c# windows forms

Tags: c#, database, winforms, sqlite, combobox

i'm trying to get multiple values from database in return, i write a code and it return me only one value but i want all values in return. i didn't know how to solve it because i'm beginner in c#. here is code

```
    string CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SV WHERE [SVCode]=@id";
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(CommandText, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", sve.SVID);
                conn.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    sve.SVName = dr["SVName"].ToString();
                    sve.SVCity = dr["SVCity"].ToString();
                    sve.SVState = dr["SVState"].ToString();
                    sve.SVEmail = dr["SVEmail"].ToString();
                    sve.SVWebsite = dr["SVWebsite"].ToString();
                    sve.SVAddress = dr["SVAddress"].ToString();
                    sve.SVNote = dr["SVNote"].ToString();
                }
                return sve.SVName; //how to return SVCity,SVState,SVEmail,SVWebsite,SVAddress,SVNote
            }


    private string SVCB(){
            SVE sve = new SVE();
            sve.SVID = MSVD_vendorcode.SelectedItem.ToString();
            sve.SVName = MSVD_vendorname.Text;
            sve.SVCity = MSVD_vendorcity.Text;
            sve.SVState = MSVD_vendorstate.Text;
            sve.SVEmail = MSVD_vendoremail.Text;
            sve.SVWebsite = MSVD_vendorwebsite.Text;
            sve.SVAddress = MSVD_vendoraddress.Text;
            sve.SVNote = MSVD_vendornote.Text;

            SVSCB sv = new SVSCB();
            return sv.SVCBSI(sve);}

    private void SVcode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MSVname.Text = SVCB();
        MSVcity.Text = SVCB();
        MSVstate.Text = SVCB();
        MSVemail.Text = SVCB();
        MSVwebsite.Text = SVCB();
        MSVaddress.Text = SVCB();
        MSVnote.Text = SVCB();
    }
```

this code working but show only one value of SVName in every textbox.

Update!!

```
    public static string SV_CBSI(SVE sve)
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(DatabaseConnection.ConnectionString()))
        {
            string CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SV WHERE [SVCode]=@id";
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(CommandText, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", sve.SVID);
                conn.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    sve.SVName = dr["SVName"].ToString();
                    sve.SVCity = dr["SVCity"].ToString();
                    sve.SVState = dr["SVState"].ToString();
                    sve.SVEmail = dr["SVEmail"].ToString();
                    sve.SVWebsite = dr["SVWebsite"].ToString();
                    sve.SVAddress = dr["SVAddress"].ToString();
                    sve.SVNote = dr["SVNote"].ToString();
                }
                return sve.SVName; //how to return SVCity,SVState,SVEmail,SVWebsite,SVAddress,SVNote
            }
        }
    }

    public static string SVCBSI(SVE sve)
    {
        return SVWCB.SV_CBSI(sve);
    }
```

here is complete code

Comment: Yes id is unique.

Comment: You should return _sve_ not a single property of sve. Please show all the code in that sql method

Comment: all code update

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a method that return the whole SVE retrieved from database given a particular SVCode.

Notice that I suppose that SVCode is an integer. If not change the input type for this method accordingly

```
public SVE SV_CBSI(int id)
{
    SVE localSve = new SVE();
    string CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SV WHERE [SVCode]=@id";
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(CommandText, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        conn.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            localSve.SVName = dr["SVName"].ToString();
            localSve.SVCity = dr["SVCity"].ToString();
            localSve.SVState = dr["SVState"].ToString();
            localSve.SVEmail = dr["SVEmail"].ToString();
            localSve.SVWebsite = dr["SVWebsite"].ToString();
            localSve.SVAddress = dr["SVAddress"].ToString();
            localSve.SVNote = dr["SVNote"].ToString();
        }
        return localSve;
    }
}
```

Now you can call this method and get back the reference to an SVE instance filled with your data.

```
private void SVcode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SVE currentSVE = SV_CBSI(Convert.ToInt32(SVCode.SelectedItem))
    MSVname.Text = currentSVE.SVName;
    MSVcity.Text = currentSVE.SVCity;
    MSVstate.Text = currentSVE.State;
    MSVemail.Text = currentSVE.SVEmail;
    MSVwebsite.Text = currentSVE.SVWebsite;
    MSVaddress.Text = currentSVE.SVAddress;
    MSVnote.Text = currentSVE.SVNote;
}
```

Comment: can you tell me please what is GetSVE ?

Comment: What error? Please explain the exact error message received.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to return an array (or a List) of strings?

Comment: But how I use arry or a list

Comment: you need to:  private string[] SVCB(){... return ...[]}